# Convert json response to null or void object

Tags: java, json, gson

My code gets the response of an HTTP call and converts the string to a Json object.

```
return gson.fromJson( String.valueOf(execute( requestInfo.getHttpRequest() )), requestInfo.getResponseType() );
```

However, the `gson.fromJson` method, requires you to specify the object to which you want to convert it to.

I do not want any response class for this particular call, and would like to return void/null. However, since this is a shared method across multiple methods, I **have to** pass in some class. At the moment, I am passing in this,

```
private static final Type RETURN_TYPE = new TypeToken<NameOfMyResponseClass>() {
    }.getType();
```

How can I replace this will null or void, so that nothing is returned?

PS : The reason I want to pass null is that, the response for this method contains a ton of members, and I do not want to create a POJO having all these members initialized so I can convert to a gson object, which is not even useful for me.

Ideally, if there was something like, that's what I am looking for.

```
private static final Type RETURN_TYPE = new TypeToken<Void>() {
        }.getType();
```

Comment: What if you simply pass a null, not a null-type definition? In such case you could even not invoke `gson.fromJson` simply returning `null` from your method yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you simply use:

```java
private static <T> T fromJson(final String json, final Type type) {
    if ( type == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

If, for some justified reason, you cannot pass the `null` to the `fromJson` method, you can create a `Void` and `void`-friendly type adapter and bind it to your `Gson` instance (of course, you cannot return a `void` "value"):

```java
final class VoidTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Void> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<Void> voidTypeAdapter = new VoidTypeAdapter();

    private VoidTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<Void> getVoidTypeAdapter() {
        return voidTypeAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Void value)
            throws IOException {
        out.nullValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Void read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        // Skip the current JSON tokens stream value entirely
        in.skipValue();
        return null;
    }

}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Void.class, getVoidTypeAdapter())
        .registerTypeAdapter(void.class, getVoidTypeAdapter())
        .create();
```

```java
private static <T> T fromJson(final String json, final Type type) {
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

```java
private static String toJson(final Object object, final Type type) {
    return gson.toJson(object, type);
}
```

So a simple test might look like this:

```java
private static void test(final Type type) {
    System.out.println(type);
    final Object value = fromJson("[\"foo\",\"bar\"]", type);
    System.out.println("-\t" + value);
    System.out.println("-\t" + toJson(value, type));
}
```

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    test(new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
    test(Void.class);
    test(void.class);
}
```

Output:

> java.util.List
>   -  [foo, bar]
>   -  ["foo","bar"]
>   class java.lang.Void
>   -  null
>   -  null
>   void
>   -  null
>   -  null

Note that type tokens are mostly used to build a type information for generic types. In more simple cases you can use `.class` to get `Class<?>`: `int.class`, `Integer.class`, `void.class`, `Void.class`, `int[][][][][].class`, etc.